# How to add pages in Zendesk?

Tags: zendesk

I am new to Zendesk and I want to add new pages in Zendesk. Can you describe to me step by step how to create these pages as it will be easy for me to learn how to complete this.

Comment: What do you mean by pages ? you mean articles in the help center ?

Answer (score 0):

In Zendesk you can not create pages. You can create articles under section. In your help center if you want to customize your design you can do that.

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203664326-Customizing-Help-Center#topic_h5c_k4w_n3